# Screen resolution doesn't persist

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, display-resolution, nvidia-settings

I just installed an NVidia GeForce GTX 750 Ti card, and I'm using the proprietary drivers from NVidia's website, on a computer running 14.04. It works perfectly... until I log out and log back in. Every time I do, it resets to low resolution, removes my overscan settings, and makes it such that the mouse actually "clicks" about an inch from where the cursor is.

There are a lot of questions that give the same solution, or some variation on it: script "nvidia-settings --load-config-only" to run as you log in. This has no effect; running it in a terminal window does nothing, nor putting it in .xinitrc.

The only way I've found to make this work is to launch nvidia-settings, then change *any* setting so that the "Apply" button becomes clickable, and click it. It then loads the settings I want. This is complicated by the fact that the mouse clicks an inch from where it's aimed until I complete the process.

Removing monitor.xml changed the default resolution, but not to what I want it to be. Disabling xrandr daemon had no effect.

Does anyone have any advice?

Relevant portion of xorg.conf:

```
Section "Monitor"
# HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
Identifier     "Monitor0"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "COB TF-TV3207E*"
HorizSync       14.0 - 91.0
VertRefresh     22.0 - 80.0
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 750 Ti"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080 +0+0 {viewportout=1818x1022+51+28}"
    Option         "SLI" "Auto"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Auto"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: I have same problems after core upgrating. What says glxinfo ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is relevant, but I believe ubuntu generally ignores xorg.conf. It does, however, create a virtual xorg.conf from various autodetected info and the xorg.conf pieces under `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`. You might try adding the stuff you want in there somehow.

Comment: Good thought, but the /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf is identical to the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file. :(

Comment: xorg.conf.d entries, like other conf-directory elements, are named e.g. 10-evdev.conf, 50-synaptics.conf, etc, to determine load order. I don't know if this matters for xorg.conf.d or if it's just a convention, but it's possible that entries without a leading 2-digit number would be ignored.

Comment: I didn't manually create any of the files in this directory, but none have any settings related to the screen other than xorg.conf. The other files all seem to relate solely to input devices. As far as I know, the two-digit order is really just ASCII sorting of the files.